# Seemingly compiler-specific failure to convert 64 bit bitset to binary string representation

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<bitset>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long long int number;
    number = 123456789123456789;
    string binary = bitset<64>(number).to_string();
    cout<<binary<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result: 0000000000000000000000000000000010101100110100000101111100010101 but it's wrong.

Info from comments (and OPs experiment):
Same code results in expected binary representation in other environments.

What is the reason?

Comment: Are you sure `long long int` is 64-bit on your platform? Because your output is exactly the number 123456789123456789 after truncating to 32 bits.

Comment: Confirming @Yksisarvinen , here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php I get output 0000000110110110100110110100101110101100110100000101111100010101 So it looks enviroment specific and suspecting variable widths is very plausible.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen yes, sizeof(long long int) is 8

Comment: Please try `number = 123456789123456789LL;`. Maybe the variable is wide enough, but stubborn compiler needs help with recognising long long numbers.

Comment: What is your environment by the way? Which compiler and version?

Comment: @Yunnosch was using dev-c++.Now will try VS.

Comment: @Yunnosch everything working OK on VS!

Comment: @Yunnosch so its just IDE. Thank you.

Comment: With or without my proposed `LL`? If with (especailly if also on first compiler) I will create an answer. If without the question could be closed as "not reproducable" (blaming the first compiler....)

Comment: @Yunnosch LL didn't change nothing

Comment: I propose to turn this into a question why dev-c++ (or the compiler used there) fails, while others succeed. You could get help in deciding whether it plausibly is a bug to be reported to compiler supplier... I close-vote as not reproducable now. But if the question gets interesting progress/answers, I will retract that.

Comment: Does `bitset` constructor indeed takes `unsigned long long` and not `unsigned long` for some reason?

Comment: Does your compiler support C++11? What is the size of `unsigned long` in your env?

Comment: @DanielLangr Why unsigned long? long long int seem the relevant width here.

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/By9WhnZajGthpqb1  
It works as expected. I think you should make sure `sizeof(long long int)` is 8.

Comment: Hello everybody, before again proposing again to again check the size of long long int or other types, please read the already existing comments, especially the very first one by WTF, the OP - to avoid turning the discussion into an endless loop.

Comment: @Yunnosch Since C++11, there was no `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @DanielLangr Now I see the relevance. What was accepted before? I think I see what you are aiming for here, but I recommend to make an answer. I will be interested and as soon as anything gets close to enlightenment here, I will retract my close vote (and have an itchy upvote finger... ;-) ).  (Um, I think you edited your comment and disconnected mine... But I think you still get my point...)

Comment: WTF, I took the liberty to refocus your question a little on the seeming compiler-dependency. I hope that is OK for you. Feel free to undo my edit.

Answer (score 5):

I can reproduce the problem under the following circumstances:

- 32-bit target architecture,
- either old GCC version or compilation against C++03.

For example, with GCC 10.2, this happens with `-m32 -std=c++03`, with GCC 4.9.2 just with `-m32`. Until C++11, there was no `unsigned long long` defined by the standard. Though C++98/03 implementations may provide it as a non-standard extension, the parameter of the constructor of `std::bitset` was of `unsigned long` type only. Which, in the above-described cases, is only 32-bit long. This is where you lost the upper bits.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/PWdY8K

The relevant part in libstdc++ is [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/bitset#L873):

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
  constexpr bitset(unsigned long long __val) noexcept
  : _Base(_Sanitize_val<_Nb>::_S_do_sanitize_val(__val)) { }
#else
  bitset(unsigned long __val)
  : _Base(__val)
  { _M_do_sanitize(); }
#endif
```

Comment: Now that is what I call "research effort".

Comment: @Yunnosch The problem was that I wasn't sure whether this caused the OP's problem. That's why I asked in the comments for clarification. Since OP haven't responded yet, I am still not sure, but guess this is the explanation they are looking for.

Comment: I'd love to have OP confirm or reject for their special case. But even if this does not allow OP to fix their original problem, your answer in itself makes a lot of sense and is well supported by experiments and historical info/links. It stays potentially helpful for others, even if not for OP. We could maybe do with a more "findable" title.

Comment: I edited the question a little, let me know if you feel that I moved it away from your answer. That would be accidental. Feel free to undo.